# height="100%" works with <object> but not with <img>, difference HTML vs CSS width/height property?

Tags: html, css, image, object, height

I've got two codes and I don't know why the use of height=100% works only on image? in other cases it does nothing and the content choose the minimum height
the object ignore it but not the image.

```
   <section id="corps">
      <object data="images/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

      </object>
      <img src="images/test.png" width="90%" height="90%">
   </section>
```

And plus, Why width and height property works in html without style = "..." but others like min-height needs it. Is it just because html support these?
Thanks!

Comment: `min-height` is a `css-property` and `width` and `height` are `css` properties and as well as `attributes` of the `html` element see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) for the complete list.

Comment: oh, so basically its just the same property's name but are they doing the same thing ? because now i can change the width to 100% it works but not height , why ? i thought that they depend on the parent's size

Comment: yes it depends on parent what i was talking about is why you can not use min-height as an attribute of the image tag,

Comment: oh ok thanks, by the way do width/height from css and with/height from html behave in the same way ? and do you have an answer for my first question ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: The attributes `height` and `width` are in CSS pixels but are not given any unit values. In other words, percent is not an allowed value for `height` or `width`. `height="100%"` is invalid for current web pages.

Comment: ok thank you i understand !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    #corps{ height: Xpx} //replace X with the value that suits you
    #corps object{height: 100%} //Now you'll get the 100% height
</style>
```

Alternatively, if you use `position: absolute` then `height: 100%` will work just fine.

About why `<img src="images/test.png" width="90%" height="90%">` works, because height and width are `HTML5` properties for images.
You can achieve the same thing by using `<img src="images/test.png" style="width: 90%; height: 90%;">`, Now this is CSS.